# Analyze Previous months data from logs using Awstats?

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, awstats

Hi I have configured Awstats on my ubuntu machine to analyze nginx access logs and the problem is Awstats gives me report only for the present day i want to analyze the previous months logs also and i have combine all logs to a single file and ran the update script still i dnt get the report for the previous months, i checked the log files the data for the previous months are in avilable what am i doing wrong

Comment: This is answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14850083/268066

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a real-time log analyzer, such as GoAccess. It's really fast and you can combine all logs. `apache & nginx`

http://goaccess.prosoftcorp.com/

```
zcat -f access.log* | goaccess -a -s -b
```

OR

```
zcat access.log.*.gz | goaccess -a -s -b
```

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was to use `logresolvemerge.pl` to create a new logfile.  I then deleted all the previous logs and used the one really big large as the access.log.  I then set it to the appropriate permissions.  Then I deleted the `domain.hash` file that stored all the awstats data.  You can find it by first looking in the `/etc/awstats/awstats.yourdomain.conf` file.  It has a location for DirData.  Mine was `/var/lib/awstats`.  After deleting that hash file, I reran the update command and it took forever.  Once it was done, I reloaded apache2 and I had all my data from the last year and a half. You might not need to reload Apache but I didn't test it before I did.